# Pstricks (Latex Draw) and Transparency are clashing?

Tags: graphics, packages, pstricks, transparency

I have a document set up with a number of pictures with a set transparency like this

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \transparent{0.4} 
  \includegraphics[width=50mm,scale=0.5]{2.png}
\end{figure}
```

I then tried to put in a figure I made using LaTeX Draw. (It's the first time I've used this program)

It requires the pstricks package to display the figures it creates. 
The problem is, now I get errors at every instance of transparency in the existing figures.
These are all the libraries I'm using

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{transparent}
```

I'm pretty new to latex so I don't totally understand how the packages work but it seems like pstricks is somehow blocking transparency from working? How can I fix this? Is there a way to say "use this package only here and nowhere else"? or do the packages necessarily apply to the whole document?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I don't know if there's a conflict, but do you know `pstricks` has an`opacity=…` key, which you may set with `\psset`?